Is this schematic for an LED power status drawn correctly?
I have a simple schematic drawn out in KiCAD for a single purple LED to light up when there is power running through to a array of 5050 RGB LEDs. The reason I'm not sure my schematic will work is because the purple LED needs 3V power, but the other 5050 LEDs run on 5V. I have tried to separate the voltages as shown below.

This is my best attempt at a solution and the connections seem to be linking correctly on the PCB side of things.
UPDATE 1: This should be the correct design now as pointed out?




simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Right now you are shorting your +5V to ground with D1. A simple 200 ohm (or so) resistor in series with the indicator LED will limit the current to 10mA from a 5V supply.
This assumes that monitoring voltage supplied to the LED string is an acceptable stand-in for current flowing through it. If you truly want to confirm current flow, then things get a little more complex.

The indicator LED can only run at 3V the other ones in the array run at 5V.

Is it a bare LED?  3V seems appropriate for the nominal forward voltage of a purple LED. The 5V array definitely has its own current limiting circuitry in there so 5V is required, but bare LEDs only care about current limiting and can run off of any voltage within reason so long as it exceeds their Vf.

Oh okay. So the LED will run off of CC through a 5V source and the resistor will limit how far that CC will go, thus the LED will never reach 5V?

Yes, assuming it's a bare LED. If it is some sort of module with a current limiting device built in already then things might be different.

Yes it is a bare LED 0805. I have updated the Question. Is the new design correct now?

I have updated my answer with a schematic.
